# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

Got this in Chrome dev console:

> Font from origin 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

However, I did this:

```
curl -I http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:51:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/font-sfnt
Content-Length: 112160
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Aug 2014 04:30:29 GMT
Expires: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 15:51:47 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30672000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So what's going on??

**EDITED**
Oh never mind, I resolved it by using `https:` instead of just `//` ..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using https: instead of just // ..

Comment: @Lucas for one you do not say where the "//" appeared, only that you changed it...